# about Yii2 log's DbTarget

Tags: logging, yii2

I want to add opreation log in **Yii2**，this is my *log config* and error info：
[my log config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOtm2.png)

[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf5BH.png)

How to resolve the problem...
thank you.

Comment: Do not post code or errors as image - paste it as text in question.

Comment: ok，thank you，i ask question here first time~

Comment: You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `except` property in your config file, it should be an array not a string, so it should look like following

```
'except' => ['yii\db\Command::query']
```

Comment: Yes, most of its'config structure are array,thank you~